# How is a response generated?

Tags: 8, routes

A generic basic PHP Application using Symfony uses code similar to the following one.

```
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$context = new RequestContext();
$context->fromRequest($request);
$matcher = new UrlMatcher($routes, $context);

try {
   $attributes = $matcher->match($request->getPathInfo());
   $response = $attributes['controller']($request);
} catch (ResourceNotFoundException $exception) {
   $response = new Response('Not Found', 404);
} catch (Exception $exception) {
   $response = new Response('An error occurred', 500);
}

$response->send();
```

In Drupal 8, the index.php file contains the following code.

```
use Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

$autoloader = require_once 'autoload.php';

$kernel = new DrupalKernel('prod', $autoloader);

$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

I tried to search for any usagee of the `UrlMatcher` class provided by Symfony, but I don't see it being used.

How does Drupal handle the URL? How does it generate the response?

Comment: As you can see Drupal is based on https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_kernel.html, which is event driven and routing is implemented in an event subscriber.